# Como criar um Auth controller personalizado em Laravel 5.5?

Tags: laravel, laravel-auth, laravel-5.5

Eu criei um controlador Auth customizado no Laravel 5.5 com a action "store", dentro dele, depois eu autentiquei usando o método `auth->attempt()` que retorna `true`. Até aí tudo certo, o problema começa quando tento usar o middleware "auth" para as rotas do meu painel, o middleware de autenticação sempre redireciona para a action de login.

**Routes:**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'web']], function () {
    Route::get('/painel/', ['as' => 'painel.dashboard', 'uses' => 'DashboardController@index']);
});

Route::get('/login', ['middleware' => 'web', 'as' => 'login', 'uses' => 'AuthController@index']);

Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::get('/painel/auth', ['as' => 'painel.auth.index', 'uses' => 'AuthController@index']);
    Route::post('/painel/auth/store', ['as' => 'painel.auth.store', 'uses' => 'AuthController@store']);
});
```

**Controller:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Applications\Painel\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;
use Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager as Auth;

class AuthController extends BaseController
{

    /**
     * @var Guard
     */
    private $auth;

    public function __construct(Guard $auth)
    {
        $this->auth = $auth;
    }

    public function index()
    {
        return view('painel::auth.index');
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->only(['email', 'password']);

        // This condition always return true, but after Laravel return to action index...
        if ($this->auth->attempt($data)) {
            return redirect()->route('painel.dashboard');
        }

        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Fala meu amigo, bom dia. Respondendo a sua pergunta, no laravel 5.5 temos vários tipos de tutoriais para fazer esse tipo de autenticação múltipla. Lhe recomendo dar uma lida nesse material que utilizei em um projeto meu tbm ([Autenticações independentes](https://medium.com/@renandiett/laravel-5-4-trabalhando-com-autentica%C3%A7%C3%B5es-independentes-sem-packages-adicionais-6e50c11a0b79)), ele trabalha com a versão 5.4, porém se vc adequar um pouco a estrutura, trabalhará bem na 5.5.

Abraços, qualquer dúvida entra em contato:

contato@brunogaignoux.com -
http://brunogaignoux.com

Comment: Embora este link possa responder à pergunta, é melhor incluir as partes essenciais da resposta aqui e fornecer o link para referência.  As respostas apenas por link podem ser invalidadas se a página com o link for alterada. - [Da Revisão](/review/low-quality-posts/157059)

Comment: @hugocsl Na verdade essa resposta está mais com cara de anúncio.

Comment: @LeandroAngelo pode até ser interpretado como Spam mesmo, mas como está dentro do assunto da Tag, e o Bruno é membro do STOF a mais de 2 anos eu revisei como "resposta por link" mesmo....

Comment: @hugocsl Fato, falha minha pelos dados de contato e site com o currículo.

Comment: Bom amigos, a minha intenção era ajudar mesmo, e como trabalho em dois projetos ao mesmo tempo, tirei um tempinho para ajudar. Realmente o meu site é um curriculo, porém lá possuem dados de contatos além desse email, para caso de dúvidas que vocês tenham, já que ultimamente eu tenho entrado pouco aqui no STOF. Espero que entendam que eu não estou tentando me promover e sim ajudar, aqui é uma comunidade aberta para dúvidas e não linkedin, ou seja, não faria sentido eu tentar me promover neste ambiente. Espero que revejam seus argumentos, abraços! @LeandroAngelo